# Constructing grid over given position from polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, polygon-creation, snapping, multi-polygon

I have the following situation: I have a MultiPolygon Layer that shows some squares with the size of 100mx100m. The data looks like a raster:

[image: Layer with MultiPolygons]

I want to construct a grid with the size of 100mx100m (rectangle(polygon)), so that it fits over the MultiPolygons. I have tried it with the grid-tool in QGIS. In the settings for the expansion parameter I have tried all options, but I always get a result like in the following picture:

[image: grid and MultiPolygon Layers]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the grid over the squares so that the grid fits perfectly over them?

Comment: You have tried different origins for the grid? Does your polygons have the same spacing?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I have tried different origins with the expansion parameter. First I have tried it with the expansion from the MultiPolygons and after that with the expansions from the boundary layer. The Polygons have all the same size and they can be anywhere in the boundarys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You know the spacing is 100m in both x and y.
2. ["Create grid"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#create-grid) via `Vector > Research Tools > Create Grid`
3. `Grid Type` - set it to `Rectangle`
4. `Grid Extent`

   1. set it to `Calculate from Layer` and select the polygon layer - it will fill in the numbers. The first 2 are the east-west range of the polygon layer, the last 2 are for north-south. The CRS of the layer is also shown.
   2. modify the coordinates by a multiple of 100m if some kind of overlap is required. This will place the origin of the grid so that grid cells are aligned with your existing polygons
5. Set `Horizontal Spacing` & `Vertical Spacing` to 100m.
6. Set the `Grid CRS` to be the same as the layer you are aligning to.
7. Press <kbd>Run</kbd>

#### Input

[image]

#### Parameters

[image]

#### Output

[image]
The extent looks long in the south because I have some transparent cells. It is correctly aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way probably is snapping the grid to the polygon layer with the squares:

1. Activate snapping (choose snap to `vertices` and `all layers`).
2. Select all features of the grid (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in Windows).
3. Toggle editing for the grid layer.
4. Select `Move feature`, click on one of the corners of the grid and move it over one of the corners of the green rectangles so that it snaps to it and you're done.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. 10 years, and I have never snapped! At first, I kept getting edges. then I selected the Vertex option in the toolbar menu `Snapping Options`

Comment: So start snapping now ;-)